# REST Client: java backend consumer vs java script consumer

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, rest-client

I want to generate webApp in java and just use some REST service. I think there are two approach for this:

1- Client side consumer: With an simple app that contain some java script file which call service and then generate UI from result.

2- Server side consumer: In backend first call service(with spring RestTemplate) then generate appropriate UI and send HTML ui to client.

Which approach is recommended?

I know this question is very general but I want to know advantage and disadvantage of those.

Comment: For 2) I would use vaadin. I have been using it and I really enjoy working with it. I find it the simplest web ui to use. It generates html5 on the client side

Comment: Option 1, Its a client agnostic. And server can produce different content types depends on client device.

Answer (score -1):

Client side consumer approach is the better one as tomorrow if you have one more client application who requires the same data but will be displaying it in a different way then client side consumer approach will benefit you. For eg: suppose the consumer today is a web page then you can get the data from backend and display it on your webpage, but tomorrow if your business grows and you plan for a mobile app then in that case your same rest api will come in handy for you.

Comment: Why approach 1 is better for create second client? Also in approach 2 I can make client easily.

Comment: But sending html over the Internet will consume more data than sending json

Comment: No. I Have to web app in this scenario, service provider and UI provider by calling web service. When I have mobile App just second part must be change with our app.

Comment: But what about data consumption? Isn't html more data consuming than json? Transferring response in json will also make your website or application fast.

Comment: Yes, json is Lighter than html. Thanks.